Level zero of multires after "Apply base" mismatch geometry
I am resculpting a bat model from a third-party using multires.
I had a problem with the arm/propatagium junction that got messed up after a Catmull-Clark subdivision since there was a 90° angle, I repaired it mostly but now multires Apply base produce strange results
The GIF below is an inner view of the arm from the wrist looking toward the chest, the "long cave" at the right is the problematic propatagium membrane that clip into themselves at subdivision level 0.
Face orientation is correct beside some clipping at the left and a wild polygon that plunge into the wrist at level zero.

From the outside the membrane get literally inside out, I think the bad topology can be a source of problems, but I cannot see why only level 0 is affected and only at this specific junction. I definitely miss things about how multires and it's Apply base operator work.
I am obviously not a professional and I would like to know what is going wrong and how to avoid and repair that.

Additional constraints
This is my resculpt scene and model with no shape keys, my main scene has the very same model but with shape keys and I use Join as Shapes to create a shape key of the resculpt, this process is non-destructive but require both models to have the exact same topology. Recreating all shape keys and vertex groups is outside my skills and affordable time.
My current workaround is to use a shrinkwarp modifier. That also produce smoother and more visually pleasing results but that is another problem. But I expect some edits to don't shrinkwarps very well so my process is going to get more complicated and I would like to avoid shrinkwarp completely. So.
What is exactly going on ?
How do I prevent that phenomenon from happening ?
And how can I repair my model ?
